# App does not load in elements when deployed

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have a strange issue regarding SharePoint apps. I have installed my own Win Server 2013 R2, SQl for dev and SharePoint 2013 SP1 January 2016 CU.

I am able to create and run custom solutions without any issues.

However, when I start debugging app, the app is deployed to the server but then when I want to view this app, I get only html code but none of the scripts, pictures (any content) are not loaded (screenshot).

I only tried to deploy out of the box apps from VS15.

[image]

I looked at development tools in Chrome and I am getting lots of errors. Do I have DNS messed up?

[image]

Comment: SharePoint 2014 ??

Comment: i installed sharepoint 2013 and then service pack 1 with january updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved it, hope it helps in the future:

when you setup your environment for add-ins (apps) development and you will face the same issue, remember, you have to create a ROOT site collection. After i reviewd ULS logs I realized that missing components are supposed to be stored in the root. I always created ex.: http://SPDevServer/sites/dev/ but I forgot to create for ex.: http://SPDevServer/root/ - after I did so, everything started to work like a charm